# OData Connector in Power BI issue

Tags: odata, integration, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence, navision

I am trying to integrate Power BI (desktop) and Dynamics NAV 2017 with OData url. I have created the OData, the link is working fine, but unfortunately when I try to connect on Power BI with the same url I get error: **"We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided"**. I assume that the problem is with Power BI configuration, since the link is working perfectly fine on web. Do I maybe need a gateway or something additional that I need to install or reconfigure? Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

- I tried deleting the global permissions and it didn't work
- I also checked "Ignore privacy level settings"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please check your settings conection ( username, password, port, timeout) should be like your credentials database, verify your port is open on your system or something fireball are blocking access

Comment: I have already checked that. Unfortunately, no progress. Thank you

Comment: What type of credentials are you using?

Comment: Credentials which can be found in Navision (user name and Web service access key).